# Как выполнить ajax запрос по onload?

Tags: ajax, javascript

Помогите по onload в <body>
выполнить ajax апрос

```
$("#kilometers").change(function(){
  var searchString = $(this).val();
  $.ajax({
      url: "index_ajax.php",             
      dataType : "html",                       
      data: "q=includes/modules/ajax/LoadCityTax.php&name="+searchString,
      type: "POST",   
      success: function(msg){$("#city").html(msg);}            
   });                     
});
```

хочу результат запроса вывести в `<input id="kilometers">`

Comment: "по onload в <body>" это как?

Comment: <body  onLoad="функция запроса()">

Comment: Так а в чем проблема? 'хочу результат запроса вывести в <input id="kilometers">'.

     function(msg){$("#city").html(msg);}
     // в input с id kilometers говорите? :)

Comment: `$("#kilometers").change(function(){/*...*/}).change();` - вот и все. Ну, и функцию обернуть в `$(function(){/* код */});` =)

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно дописать там где у вас лежит скрипт с ajax-запросом

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#kilometers').trigger('change');
});
```

или же просто внутри $(document).ready()

```
$('#kilometers').trigger('change');
```

Comment: т.е такая конструкция?

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#kilometers").trigger("change");
  $("#kilometers").change(function(){
      var searchString = $(this).val();
      $.ajax({
              url: "index_ajax.php",             
              dataType : "html",                       
              data: "q=includes/modules/ajax/LoadCityTax.php&name="+searchString,
              type: "POST",   
              success: function(msg){$("#kilometers").html(msg);}            
              });                     
    });     
});
 </script>

Comment: $("#kilometers").trigger("change"); - после поставьте

    $(document).ready(function() {
         $("#kilometers").change(function(){
            var searchString = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "/echo/html/",
                dataType : "html",
                data: "q=includes/modules/ajax/LoadCityTax.php&name="+searchString,
                type: "POST",
                success: function(msg){$("#city").html(msg);}
            });
        });
        $("#kilometers").trigger("change");
    });

Comment: P.S. Кстати, @ling предложил вам наиболее лаконичное решение. Но посути это одно и то же. Просто триггер можно использовать в разных случаях и при разных событиях

Comment: чет я совсем еду разумом(((
из 
<input type="text" id="city" value="'.$city.'"" />
надо достать значение и после ajax обработки засунуть его в 
<input type="text" id="kilometers" name="kilometers"  />';

а в скрипте пишу function(msg){$("#city").html(msg);
бда(((

Comment: Вопрос был "**ajax запрос по onload**", теперь мы куда-то с темы съезжаем в сторону "**надо достать значение и после ajax обработки засунуть его** (не скажу куда)"